# Populate checkboxes depending on child node picked from treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, treeview

I have a `TreeView` and on a separate `panel` 3 `checkboxes`.
The Treeview data is being pulled from a database,this database has two tables `Product` and `Model` inside the `Model` table there are 3 `columns` - `twoDoor`, `threeDoor` and `fiveDoor`.
My TreeView looks like this;

```
CAR(PRODUCT)
 ->FORD(MODEL)
 ->BMW(MODEL)
 ->VW(MODEL)
```

On a separate panel there are 3 `checkboxes`;

- Two Door
- Three Door
- Five Door

The state of these `checkboxes` are already defined in the `Model` db.
How can i display their state against whatever child Node(Model) is picked in the `TreeView`?

My Code:

```
  private void Form1_Options_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String connectionString;

        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        String Sequel = "SELECT id,ProductName,ModelType FROM Product";

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Sequel, conn);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        conn.Open();

        da.Fill(dt);



        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {

            parentNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add(dr["ProductName"].ToString());
            //treeView1.Nodes.Add(dr["ModelType"].ToString());

           PopulateTreeView(Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"].ToString()), parentNode);

        }
    }

   public void PopulateTreeView(int parentId, TreeNode parentNode)
    {

        String Seqchildc = "Select * From Model WHERE ProductId = "+ parentId + "";


        SqlDataAdapter dachildmnuc = new SqlDataAdapter(Seqchildc, conn);

        DataTable dtchildc = new DataTable();

        dachildmnuc.Fill(dtchildc);

        TreeNode childNode;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dtchildc.Rows)

        {

            if (parentNode == null)

                childNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add(dr["ModelName"].ToString());
                //childNode.Nodes.Add(dr["ModelType"].ToString());

            else

                childNode = parentNode.Nodes.Add(dr["ModelName"].ToString());




            //PopulateTreeView(Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"].ToString()), childNode);

        }




        treeView1.ExpandAll();
        //Connect();


    }
```

Comment: How do you populate your tree view, i.e. is there some association between `TreeNode` and `Product`/`Model` classes?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, Yes i have a Product.cs and Model.cs

Comment: Hi. I mean, when creating nodes, do you put the objects you use somewhere - for instance in the node `Tag`?

Comment: I have added  the Form Load , a PopulateTreeView.

Comment: Could i do something like this? - `   string two = dr["twoDoor"].ToString();
                ckbTwoDoor.Items.add(two,true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do if I understand correctly the question.

First, create a class to hold your `Model` information:

```
class ModelInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool TwoDoor { get; set; }
    public bool ThreeDoor { get; set; }
    public bool FiveDoor { get; set; }
}
```

Second, modify your `PopulateTreeView` method as follows:

```
public void PopulateTreeView(int parentId, TreeNode parentNode)
{

    // ...    

    foreach (DataRow dr in dtchildc.Rows)
    {
        // Populate model info from the data
        var modelInfo = new ModelInfo { Name = dr["ModelName"].ToString() };
        //modelInfo.TwoDoor = dr[...];
        //modelInfo.ThreeDoor = dr[...];
        //modelInfo.FiveDoor = dr[...];

        // Create and add a new node
        var childNode = (parentNode == null ? treeView1.Nodes : parentNode.Nodes).Add(modelInfo.Name);

        // Associate info with the node
        childNode.Tag = modelInfo;
    }

    // ...              
}
```

The essential part is to store the `ModelInfo` inside the `Node.Tag` property so it can be retrieved later.

Finally, subscribe to the [TreeView.AfterSelect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect(v=vs.110).aspx) event and put inside the event handler something like this:

```
// Get the model info from the selected node
var modelInfo = e.Node != null ? e.Node.Tag as ModelInfo : null;
// Update the checkboxes accordingly
chkTwoDoor.Checked = modelInfo != null && modelInfo.TwoDoor;
chkThreeDoor.Checked = modelInfo != null && modelInfo.ThreeDoor;
chkFiveDoor.Checked = modelInfo != null && modelInfo.FiveDoor;
```

for the two-state checkbox style, or alternatively

```
chkTwoDoor.CheckState = modelInfo == null ? CheckState.Indeterminate : modelInfo.TwoDoor ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked;
chkThreeDoor.CheckState = modelInfo == null ? CheckState.Indeterminate : modelInfo.ThreeDoor ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked;
chkFiveDoor.CheckState = modelInfo == null ? CheckState.Indeterminate : modelInfo.FiveDoor ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked;
```

for the tri-state checkbox style.

Comment: Thanks, Ivan, when i click on a ``ParentNode` it throws a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Oops, sorry, the condition was wrong - I was thinking to include a code for tri state, then decided not to, and of course left the wrong condition. Of course it should be `!= null && ...`

Comment: Thanks,  could you edit one condition for tri state?